# Linear map which sends all but finitely many basis vectors to zero is continuous

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, operator-theory

I was thinking over the following problem for some time, but didn't get much idea:

Let $X,Y$ be normed linear spaces, and let $ f : X \rightarrow Y$  be a linear map. Further assume that there exists a Hamel basis $\mathfrak{B}$ of X having the property that only finitely many elements of $\mathfrak{B}$ are mapped to non zero elements of $Y$. Then is $f$ necessarily continuous?

Any hint will be appreciated. Also, what happens if we assume that $X$ is complete?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this is not the case, even assuming $X$ is complete. Take your favourite discontinuous linear functional $f$ on your favourite infinite-dimensional normed linear space $X$. The kernels of discontinuous linear functionals on $X$ are codimension-$1$ subspaces of $X$, and hence any Hamel basis of $\operatorname{ker} f$ can be extended to a Hamel basis of $X$ by adding a single vector. Thus, $f$ sends every vector in this basis for $X$ to $0$, except that single added vector, but $f$ is not continuous.